# Monotouch + Dragging the image in UIScrollview, bounces back to Top left corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

What I am trying to do is: I have an `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView` for Zooming purposes. Now when I zoom out, I should be able to move/pan the image anywhere on the screen. For this I have a `UIscrollView` (parent) which has the `UIScrollview`(child) with the Image.

The code I used is:

```
    void SetTestImageSettings()
    {
        //mainScrollView is Parent scrollview.


        mainScrollView = new UIScrollView (
            new RectangleF (this.mainImgView.Frame.X, this.mainImgView.Frame.Y, this.mainImgView.Frame.Width +50
                        , this.mainImgView.Frame.Height +50));
        mainScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (mainScrollView.Frame.Width + 500, mainScrollView.Frame.Height + 500);
        mainScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        mainScrollView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;

        //I tried implementing these events, but I am not sure, what to set, I mean I know I should add contentOffset, but what value?

        mainScrollView.WillEndDragging += HandleWillEndDragging;
        mainScrollView.DraggingEnded += HandleDraggingEnded;



        // create our scroll view that has Image
        scrollView = new UIScrollView (
            new RectangleF (this.mainImgView.Frame.X, this.mainImgView.Frame.Y, this.mainImgView.Frame.Width
                        , this.mainImgView.Frame.Height - toolBar.Frame.Height));

        mainScrollView.AddSubview (scrollView);
        View.AddSubview (mainScrollView);

        // create our image view
        imageView = new UIImageView (mainImage);
        scrollView.ContentSize = imageView.Image.Size;
        scrollView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
        scrollView.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.AddSubview (imageView);

        // set allow zooming
        scrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 3f;
        scrollView.MinimumZoomScale = .1f;          
        scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) => { return imageView; };


    }
```

Now every time, I drag ends, the child crollview(with image) bounces back at top left corner.

Any help would be appreciated. Also any Objective-C developer's help too would be appreciated. I hope I sound sane and clear with my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using constraints in UIScrollView? Also, try this: scrollView.bounces = NO;

Comment: I did that, and result was: The image didn't even pan in the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative I used is: I got rid of the `UIScrollview` and added gestures on the `UIImageView` itself. Pan, and Pinch gesture, where I can zoom, and also Pan/move my image on the screen. It is simpler now, and also under my control :)